# Dubious error messages in Eclipse (CDT) while build succeeds

Tags: c++, qt, indexing, eclipse-cdt

Using the **Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Linux Developers** (Version: **Indigo** Release) with **g++ 4.1.2** (on **Scientific Linux CERN 5** = RHEL 5), I currently work on a project where I make use of a **Qt4** GUI as well as Apache's **log4cxx** framework and of some C++ standard classes. 
I have installed **Nokia**'s "Qt Eclipse Integration for C++" plugin, which automatically configured Qt toolchain support (qmake, etc.).

Up until now I got everything running. My program compiles well. Except for some warnings (which are reasonable), I observe a successful build process on Eclipse's console. 
Unfortunatetly, at the same time I get about 150 error messages in the "Problems" window.

Some examples:

For the line

```
using namespace log4cxx;
```

I get

```
Symbol log4cxx could not be resolved
```

and for

```
std::vector<View*>& Model::GetRegisteredViews() { ... }
```

I get

```
Symbol vector could not be resolved
```

and

```
Member declaration not found  
    (-> of GetRegisteredViews() although the decl. is available,  
    code compiles!)
```

All error messages are also marked with annotation symbols in the editor window, which is quite annoying.

From the stackoverflow forums I have learned that it might have to do with the fact that I had two versions of gcc installed, namely **4.1.2** and **4.4**. I have already uninstalled 4.4 (using the package management system of RHEL, yum) - without success.

It might also have to do with the indexer, but frankly I have no idea where to start fixing this problem.

To me, it looks like Eclipse misses some include or library path entries, but both are mentioned in the Qt pro file as well as in Eclipse's project settings...

Your help would be highly appreciated, 
thank you for your comments!

Comment: It's probably the indexer...the project files shouldn't matter here, it would be the Eclipse/CDT configuration.  By the way, why did you ditch 4.4 for 4.1.2?  Isn't that know to be a buggy compiler?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! And thanks for the hint with the buggy compiler. I will install 4.4 rather than 4.1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Qt *per se* - it's the CDT Indexer and the Qt Eclipse Integration plugin fighting.  I find that performing a clean sometimes 'resets' the includes list in CDT project settings (only does this with Qt integration plugin running), but because Qt uses the .pro file - the compilation succeeds but CDT's CODAN (which uses the Eclipse project settings) throws a fit.

It's intensely irritating, and I haven't found a fix.  Also Qt haven't updated the Qt Eclipse Integration for awhile, they want people to use Qt Creator - but it's awful for general development.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've appreciated it! I turned off the indexer - without success. 
Do you know how to turn off "ONLINE error parsing" in Eclipse Indigo?

Comment: It won't switch off with the indexer (in fact keep that on, otherwise searching won't work properly), it's done here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis#Customize